# Annotate number of identical items in manager

Tags: django, django-managers, django-annotate

Let's say I have following simplified model:

```
class CurrentInvoices(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CurrentInvoices, self).get_queryset()
        current_invoices = qs.order_by('person', '-created_on').distinct('person').values('pk')
        return qs.annotate(invoice_count=models.Count('number')).filter(id__in=current_invoices).order_by('person__last_name')

class Invoice(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField()
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    objects = models.Manager()
    current_invoices = CurrentEDCInvoices()
```

A Person can have an `Invoice` with the same `number` if for some reason the previously generated invoice was wrong. The latest one (highest `created_on`) is the one that counts.

The trick with `.filter(id__in)` in the manager is needed to get the results listed by `person`s last name; this cannot be removed.

Now I'd like to annotate the total count of `number`.
My try `annotate(invoice_count=models.Count('number'))` always returns `1` even though there are multiple.

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers on how to properly achieve this without hacking around too much and **without hitting the DB** for every invoice?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem in `distinct('person')`, which removes duplicates by `person` field.

**Update**

To complete your task you should

```
current_invoices = qs.order_by('person', '-created_on').distinct('person').values('number')
return qs.annotate(invoice_count=models.Count('number')).filter(number__in=current_invoices).order_by('person__last_name')
```

Comment: But all invoices with the same number are linked to the same patient?

Comment: If you need to exclude invoice duplicates, you should distinct by `pk`

Comment: Hmm, I want to distinct by person, since I want to have "one line" per person. Also, distinct by pk doesn't make sense since pk is unique?

Comment: Your invoice have unique `pk` and duplicating `number`. Am I right?
You want to count duplicating numbers.
Your query set for `current_invoices` will return `pk`s of last invoices for each person, i.e. for only one invoice for each person.
So the annotate query will go only through this `pk`s and return only `1` count for each number.

Comment: Correct: unique `pk`, duplicating `number`. Indeed, the problem is that I only get one count. But how to solve this? By removing `distinct('person')` the problem might be gone, but I need only one result per person.

Comment: `I need only one result per person.` what do you mean? You want to calculate the number of invoices (with or w/o duplicates?) per person? Or for each invoice of person the number of duplicating `number`s?

Comment: My queryset should consist out of 1 result per `person`. So if I loop over all objects, I'd just get the `latest('created_on')` per `person`. However each result should be annotated with the total number of invoices available with the same number for that patient.

Comment: Further more only one `latest('created_on'‌​)` per `person`, i.e. if `person` have two different invoices with different `number`, you will get only last one. Well to complete your task you should `current_invoices = ...values('number')` and `...filter(number__in=current_invoices)...`